# JavaFX Task/Service Display Alert

Tags: javafx

Hi I am trying to implement a simple socket that transfers files/text on LAN. Naturally I used a JavaFX Application Thread to display the main UI (the client thread), and used a separate thread to implement a `ServerSocket` that "accepts" incoming connections (the server thread). While the UI is loaded, when I tried to display an `Alert` in the server thread it wouldn't let me because I am not on the JavaFX Application thread anymore. I tried to:

1. use `Platform.runlater()` in the server thread to invoke an `Alert` like this:

   ```
   //inside the run() method of the Server class, which implements Runnable
   Platform.runLater(() -> {
       Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
       alert.setContentText("This shows that it works.");
       alert.show();
   });

   //and in Main class, which defines and displays GUI
   Thread server = new Thread(new Server());
   server.start();
   ```
2. I also tried to instantiate a `JFXPanel` in the server thread which is supposed to implicitly instantiate a JavaFX Application object (I guess)
3. Convert the server thread to a `javafx.concurrent.Task` and create a new subclass of `javafx.concurrent.Service` that instantiates a server "`Task`"

But so far I can't get it to work. For the first and third approach, the GUI hangs indefinitely and for the second approach, an `IllegalStateException` is thrown indicating that I am not on the JavaFX Application thread.

Is there a way to safely display an `Alert` (or other components like `FileChooser` of that sort) in a thread other than the JavaFX Application thread? Thanks!

Comment: The first approach, using `Platform.runLater()` should work. Can you show the code for that approach?

Comment: The code you posted [works just fine for me](https://gist.github.com/james-d/e9a2f195ffef56e7481f). Your errors must be somewhere else in your code.